# Accessing display 0 using x11vnc

Tags: nvidia, gpu, x11vnc

I have a RHEL 7.8 Linux machine with Nvidia GPU. I can't access it's console so I am accessing it through VNC session.

Using `Xvnc`, I don't have access Nvidia GPU as Xvnc loads a headless X11 server.

So I configured X server to run on display 0 with `AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration` option set to `true`, but if I started X server with this configuration and then `x11vnc -display :0`, I have a black screen with only mouse cursor.

Comment: Sounds line you're successfully connecting to the X server on display 0, but if you started *only* the X server and no session processes for it, a black screen with only a mouse cursor is exactly what you would get.

Comment: sorry I am new to playing around X server setup , what exact session processes do you mean ?